# can't avdmanager and other SDK tools with same java version

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-manager, avd-manager

I have OracleJDK 8,9 and 10 installed on my arch linux laptop . When I try to run advmanager I get error like this wieh java 9 and hava 10 :-

```
% avdmanager list device                                                               :(
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 5 more
```

But with Java 8 it runs fine .But now With java other SDK tools wont run . likle sdkmanager

```
% sdkmanager --update               
Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee
```

How can I overcome this ?

I am using Android SDK 26.1.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077881/5952645 Check this for the fix.