# Ubuntu getting Module java.se.ee after set on path

Tags: java, ubuntu

as I get `java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found` error when I try to update android sdk I set this paths on `/etc/environment`:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle"
export JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
export SDKMANAGER_OPTS='--add-modules java.se.ee'
```

and after run this command:

```
source /etc/environment
```

I dont get any message on terminal, now this command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

show me this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
```

**UPADATE:**

i install OpenJDK

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b01-1-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b01, mixed mode)
```

and after set as default that i get error too

Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee

restarting ubuntu - terminal and `source /etc/environment` command couldnt resolve my problem

`DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` on sdkmanager file content:

```
#DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME"'
```

Comment: Perhaps try Java 8 instead. Maybe a comparability issue.

Comment: @J_D my post updated

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue on Ubuntu.

And just solved by running the below command in the terminal

> unset JAVA_OPTS