# Andorid Studio - Gradle - Could not find or load main class java.se.ee

Tags: java, gradle, build

I recently installed the latest jdk8 from oracle (1.8.0_212) on my Mac (MacOS 10.14).

When I try to run gradle, both inside and outside of Android Studio I get the following:

```
➜  ~ gradle
Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee
```

or

```
ERROR: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee
```

I have tried adding the following as an environment varible:

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

I have also added the following to my gradle-wrapper.properties file in Android Studio:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee
```

I also have tried reverting back to an older version of jdk8 but the issue still persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077881/5952645 Check this for the fix.