# JavaSDK 8 missing java.se.ee under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, java-8, ionic4

I have a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 machine and I am trying to compile an Ionic4 app for android but cannot pass the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee
```

I already switched to openSDK8 and configured the JAVA_HOME variable but with no luck.
Is there a way to fix or overcome this error?

I also tried to add

```
JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

To the .bashrc file without success

Here is the output of ionic cordova plugin list is:

```
cordova-clipboard 1.1.1 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.0.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-battery-status 2.0.1 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-brightness 0.1.5 "Brightness"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.15 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-fullscreen 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-fullscreen"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.6 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativeaudio 3.0.9 "Cordova Native Audio"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-networkinterface 2.0.0 "NetworkInterface"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 2.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.6 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: Java 8 has no modules. Java Modules were introduced with Java 9.

Comment: Yea.  This is not making a lot of sense. According to what I have seen, building Ionic apps for Android requires Java 8 ([Cordova doesn't support Java 11](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android)).  But the app you are trying to compile apparently is using Java 9+ modules.  Can you tell us what app you are trying to build?  Is the source code available to look at?

Comment: This is the most logic answers I have received so far. I just updated the post with the list of plugins I am using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077881/5952645 Check this for the fix.